# What happens during simultaneous hits on a tank

Tags: combat, armors, kinetic-weapons

For various reasons I have an army that uses many smaller vehicles instead of spending a lot of full main battle tanks. This army uses mostly up to 90mm* cannons on their vehicles rather than the massive 120mm+ cannons that adorn most MBTs today.

If you shoot a 90mm cannon against something like the front of an Abrams tank you can practically fire one all day and not punch through the armor. To combat this my army has developed a simultaneous hit method, allowing multiple vehicles to hit the same target and overcome its armor.

The question is, does this work and how well would it work?

There's 4 parameters that I can see:

- The grouping of the shot. If they hit a meter away from each other they'll do less damage then if the shells are practically touching each other when they hit the armor.
- The timing of the shot. If they hit simultaneously they'll likely do more damage than if they hit with 0.1 second between hits.
- The scalability of shots hitting simultaneously around a spot. 2 shots will deal less damage then 3 etc.
- Hitting in tandem instead. Hitting the exact same spot, meaning that as one shell explodes the next one is almost hitting it as well.

Please note that the implications of the accuracy or situation in which this can happen is not part of this question, just the implications of simultaneous hits

***** Subject to change if necessary to something smaller or larger. The main point is that the cannon isn't able to significantly damage the armor it's firing at in single shots.

Comment: Even if it worked, multiple vehicles means multiplied costs, so this hypothetical army is already losing badly on the economic aspect, in terms of the multiplied base cost of the vehicle itself, multiplied supplies (fuel, ammo, parts)/transport/maintenance costs of the vehicle on the battlefield, combat+maintenance crew acquisition and training costs, etc.  And of course, vehicle and crew losses are higher too since their enemy takes less shots to kill them; bad for morale of the army and their families at home.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan since even America has a larger fleet of AFV'S than MBT's I think its a bit more nuanced than that.

Comment: Hitting it with two shells in (as close as possible to) the same spot at the same time is probably strictly worse (to some unknown degree) than hitting it with a shell that's twice as big at the same speed. The two shells would have (at most) the exact same force and amount of explosives than a double-sized shell, but it would be less focused and the design may not be optimal for that purpose (a shell is designed to be most effective when hitting as a single shell). But this is not an answer because I have no idea how effective a double-sized shell would be.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Giving every modern MBT a 230mm canon would mean you can penetrate from any direction because it's almost twice the size of current guns and much more volume+kinetic energy behind it. But there's limitations to consider because we can't just slap a 230mm canon on every tank and expect it to do the MBT role. This question is specific about a group with a greater limitation using smaller cannons, any answer about "use bigger one's instead" might as well be "you want to defeat these dragons in a fantasy setting? Bring a sci-fi railgun!". It doesn't make sense with the question.

Comment: You are balancing between accuracy and precision - One gun hitting the same spot twice has high precision, two guns hitting the same spot means that one of the guns has high accuracy, conventionally - though in a networked-gun scenario one might argue it's all one weapon, and thus about precision as well. Where i am going with this: If the guns are accurate&precise enough to sequentially hit a specific spot, they may be interested in defeating tanks by targetting their comms & viewports, rather than gnawing at their armor. Fling APFSDS - Armor Painting Fin Stabilised Distracting Sh** :-)

Comment: "'use bigger one's instead' might as well be 'you want to defeat these dragons in a fantasy setting? Bring a sci-fi railgun!'" - if the best point of comparison to what you're asking is a sci-fi railgun, and people have looked into what a sci-fi railgun would do, then I can't think of anything *more* applicable to the question. I didn't mean to imply you should just use a bigger gun/shell, but rather just that looking into the damage a bigger shell would do could give some insight into the damage 2 smaller shells would do (although it's mostly an upper limit, which is only so useful).

Comment: @bukwyrm *The implications of the accuracy or situation in which this can happen is not part of this question, just the implications of simultaneous hits*

Comment: @NotThatGuy Are you saying that in a question about what simultaneous hits can do, it's better to talk about what a bigger bullet can do which doesn't in any way answer the question? So if someone on here asks about a lumberjack having to use an axe to defend himself, it's A-OK to answer "He should have brought a sword instead!"? Because that's about the same ballpark. It doesn't fit the question or the narrative.

Comment: What kind of round are they firing? Heat, sabot, what? Also against what kind of armor?

Comment: @John all rounds that have any use against modern armor (so a HESH round used against bunkers is out). There's many armor types with varying effectiveness against different ammo types and the arms industry hasnt even discovered a way to properly define their effectiveness besides the somewhat misleading RHS penetration values that dont tell the whole story, and I'm not asking you to do better than them. I'm hoping for a generalized answer as to what simultaneous hits could achieve, you get free reign to pick the ammo type you think is best rather than me constraining you.

Comment: @Demigan Is there any part of my comments you didn't understand? Because I already explained how using a bigger shell relates to using two shells in my first comment, and then I clarified it in the second comment. I don't think I can make it much clearer than I did in those comments.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I understand your comments fine, my point is that I'm not interested in using bigger shells, I'm interested in the effects of using multiple smaller shells that simultaneously hit on the same target and what it does to the armor specifically.

Answer (score 22):

Sounds like a weirdly roundabout way of making a [tandem warhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem-charge).

[image: Spike antitank missile diagram]

This is apparently a [Spike antitank missile](https://www.army-technology.com/projects/gill/), which uses such a tandem charge. In real life, this is done to evade [reactive armour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_armour), specifically the explosive kind, and isn't so good against other kinds.

> The grouping of the shot. If they hit a meter away from each other they'll do less damage then if the shells are practically touching each other when they hit the armor.

Most likely, if they can't penetrate the armour then they'll do nothing, not just "less". Grinding down the target is something that works well in computer games, but less so in real life. Light tanks should try to flank tougher opponents, hit them in the weak spots or just disable them rather than trying to blast their way through the main armour.

> The timing of the shot. If they hit simultaneously they'll likely do more damage
> than if they hit with 0.1 second between hits.

Depends on the kind of shell, but explosive rounds going off at *almost* the same time right next to each other risk having one disrupt the other and limit its effectiveness. Two armour penetrating rounds can't usefully do much hitting next to each other (cos you'll make a wider hole, not a deeper one) and there's no guarantee that hitting in the exact same spot one after another will dig a deeper hole either.

> The scalability of shots hitting simultaneously around a spot. 2 shots will deal less damage then 3 etc.

It is also a lot less likely, right? If you need to plan for that sort of occurrence, it seems like you've already shown that your tactics and weapons are terrible, and one or other has to change.

> Hitting in tandem instead. Hitting the exact same spot, meaning that as one shell explodes the next one is almost hitting it as well.

...and so you've reinvented the tandem charge warhead, but in a really awkward way that requires microsecond precision from chemical powered guns with human manufacturing tolerances probably being fired from a bumpy platform by stressed crew.

But at least you know that the basic idea is sound, and has been tested in the real world ;-)

Comment: You say "most likely" it will do nothing if one cannot penetrate. That is why I ask the question: what will happen with simultaneous hits? If you hit it with 50 shots simultaneously the armor wouldnt hold up. But what if its "just" two or three shots? Simultaneous hits cause different damage. I know artillery can use different arcs to get 2 or 3 shots to land almost simultaneously on one target, but that is giant HE rounds rather than something like a 90mm AP, HEAT or other type of round.

Comment: @Demigan as I said, simultaneous AP doesn't really work, because you'll be making a wide hole rather than a deep enough one. Simultaneous explosive risks disrupting the effects of one shell with another shell. Tanks with lighter armaments flanked tanks with heavy forward armour, and tanks with all-around super-armour were too slow and lumbering to be useful, and were vulnerable in other ways. Your idea is vastly more complex than just flanking, and isn't obviously any more practical.

Comment: if it was about individual shots I would agree, but if hits are simultaneous I dont think it will be anywhere the same. Will it penetrate? I dont know, it could. As for explosions disrupting each other, that only applies if the explosion moves through the path of the other explosion through the arnor, which ERA does. But since the shells explode on contact with the armor the shockwaves would rather create an interference pattern of peaks and lows where these shockwaves meet. The peaks would have a higher chance of cracking or creating spalls. Integrity would fall faster.

Comment: @Demigan HESH is a bit rubbish though, so it isn't used for anti-armour stuff these days. Nearby explosions _will_ disrupt HEAT-like stuff (including EFP), and as those kinds of warhead are an excellent way to pack armour-penetrating power into a smaller, lighter space that seems like bad news for your plan, no?

Comment: As for flanking, if it were so easy then tank armor would be designed for that, rather than focussing on frontal hits. And yes any army in such a situation would use flanking if necessary. Even America has more AFV's than it has MBT's (about 3x as much if I remember correctly), so if a hypothetical method to beat armor from the front could be added I dont doubt they would jump at the chance. But for that the question remains: what can we say with certainty would happen if multiple shells hit the same target near simultaneously?

Comment: @Demigan it was _done_. Like, historically, in tank battles. Frontal hits are the most common, and mass allowance for armour is limited, so you compromise on making heavy front armour and lighter elsewhere, and inevitably people will try and flank you if at all possible.

Comment: Actually HEAT rounds are a perfect example why this could work. The individual speed of the projectile and its explosive payload isnt useful on its own, but its simultaneous explosion upon contact with the armor is what allows it to work. I wont pretend that 2 shells hitting simultaneously will have the same effect as the carefully positioned explosives and materials in a HEAT shells, but its a proof of concept of the method. That said, the HEAT shells would definitely disrupt each other if they dont explode *simultaneously* as it wouldnt be able to explode "normally".

Comment: @Demigan ...which is why I gave you an answer talking about tandem HEAT warheads

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121113/discussion-between-demigan-and-starfish-prime).

Comment: You completely misunderstand the point of the dual warheads.  The first warhead exists **only** to destroy any reactive armor in the way and expose the tank armor underneath to the main warhead.  Two targets, not a 1-2 punch against one target.

Comment: @LorenPechtel did you read the second sentence of my answer?

Comment: Seems like you might want to get out the solid shot and try to beat it apart.

Answer (score 5):

In principle it can work, practically speaking it is highly unlikely.

Energy wise, when the shell hits the target, its kinetic energy is transferred to it. Same happens with the additional energy of the explosion, if the shell is explosive.

What happens next?

If the kinetic energy is higher than what the target can take in the area interested by impact, the target will be damaged. If instead the energy is not sufficient to break the physical continuity of the target, that energy will be converted into heat.

That heat will be then dissipated to the surrounding environment by the usual transfer mechanisms.

This is similar to what happens if you hammer a piece of metal: it will heat up.

If the fire cadence in a specific area is high enough to prevent it from dissipating the heat, it will eventually reach a temperature where it will become more plastic and yield to the impactor.

However you need to consistently hit always the same spot with a very high cadence, that's why it highly unlikely.

Comment: Modern tank armour is made (partly) of hard ceramics which do suffer from multiple non-penetrating hits on the same plate of armour due to simply shattering. Further, even WW2 era pure steel armour suffered from embrittlement when exposed to multiple hits - this was a problem in testing against captured enemy tanks, where multiple firing tests were performed against the same area and gave the illusion of weaker armour for later hits in the series

Answer (score 5):

Your concept has already been trialled in the [RDF/LT prototype light tank program](https://www.militaryfactory.com/armor/detail.asp?armor_id=655). However, it differs from your premise in that this is a single vehicle intended to inflict multiple near-simultaneous hits on the "same" spot of a target vehicle.

For **multiple** ground vehicles to even attempt this would likely require a form of networked computing to synchronise their shots. This in turn brings up the issue of electronic countermeasures, a thing which already exists in the real world. Effective ECM jamming would immediately cause your concept to fall apart. Even when it doesn't, it would require your multiple light vehicles to all engage one target from a similar angle, which runs counter to real life military doctrine and general good sense.

In short, the concept as originally presented is too impractical to work against an actual enemy. Starfish has the right idea.

PS: There is a platform where your idea has sort of been implemented though: the [A-10's GAU-8 gatling gun, the one the entire plane is developed around](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAU-8_Avenger). What doesn't work for ground vehicle(s) can work just fine on a single dedicated ground attack aircraft.

Comment: It's worth noting that the A-10's GAU-8 was designed for use against the thinner top armor of tanks. There's a reason why we don't see tanks developed around carrying a gun like that around.

Comment: I specifically mentioned that the accuracy or situation didnt matter in the hopes of avoiding the ineviteable "but you know what's more practical?" Answers. Thanks for at least providing a source that the tandem idea was at least considered at one point.

Comment: The linked article seems to have an incorrect model number for the RDF/LTs cannon?  The correct model number seems to be the XM274 ARES 75mm cannon.  Some interesting links are https://defense-and-freedom.blogspot.com/2010/04/medium-calibre-allround-option.html and https://forum.cartridgecollectors.org/t/help-me-find-information-for-the-xm274-75mm-autocannon-ammo-ares-gun/41145.  From what little is said, it seems it wasn't projected to be able to penetrate the frontal armor of Soviet MBTs.

Comment: @Demigan  It's not a tandem impact weapon; firing rate of the XM274 was 60 rounds / minute or 1 round / sec.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan It was intended to be used as one in the anti-armour role, and billed as such to the US Army. The rate of fire is an accessory after the concept

Comment: Thanks, brilliant info!

Answer (score 3):

There is Soviet Union Anti-Aircraft system called [Shilka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZSU-23-4_Shilka). I have heard stories that it can, using it 4 23 mm rapid fire autocannons, damage not only aircrafts, but fortifications and even dated tanks.

As they say in wiki

> Despite its present obsolescence as a modern short-range anti-aircraft
> weapon, the ZSU-23-4 is still deadly for enemy light armoured
> vehicles, infantry and firing points as an infantry-support vehicle.
> With its high rate of accurate fire, the ZSU-23-4 can even neutralize
> tanks by destroying their gun sights, radio antennas, or other
> vulnerable parts.

So, if we have modern tank caught by cross fire of few Shilkas, its armor will probably survive, but we cannot say the same about crew inside or other onboard machinery (targeting systems, motivators, tracks, engines air intakes, anthenas, etc...). Probably, tank ammunition can detonate inside it.

Most likely crew will be shocked by loud sounds of `Shilka` ammunition damaging armor of tank, and likely to be hit by pieces of tank armour, that falls appart fron internal layer, when external layer of armour is deformed.

UPD: continuous exposure for "Shilka"'s fire sooner or later can damage even frontal armor of modern tank (lets say, it can survive ~ 1-2 minutes under fire), but tank still have good chances to fight back and score "Shilka" - it has quite basic armor. But things can be changes if there is ambush of few "Shilkas" against tank.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. It wasnt about what it could do to non-tank targets or how it could demolish items on the outside of the tank. The question is specifically about what it does to the armor. As mentioned in your article the Shilka is deadly against light vehicles, it does not pose a deadly threat against full tanks (from the front at least).

Answer (score 2):

**Explosion from first shell could damage second.**

First some assumptions.  We are talking about (from OP)

> Hitting in tandem instead. Hitting the exact same spot, meaning that
> as one shell explodes the next one is almost hitting it as well.

You observe that hitting the tank twice a meter apart at the same time offers no special benefits.  Two shells hitting the exact same spot at the same time is not possible because these are not phantom shells - each occupies space.  So the best you can do if you are hitting the same exact spot is to hit it twice in rapid succession.

You risk interfering with the second shell because of the explosion of the first.  Shells can be deflected by explosion.  There is armor that does this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_armour#Explosive_reactive_armour

The explosion of the armor disrupts the energy of the incoming projectile by various means depending on the type of projectile - changing its trajectory, wasting some of its explosive power and so on.

If your second shot is tailgating your first it will run headlong into fast moving shrapnel and armor pieces produced by the explosion of the first.  This will slow it down if nothing else.  More seriously a hit on the incoming projectile could cause it to turn and so hit the tank sideways or at an angle, not with its hardened nose.   At worse the explosion damages the second shell such that it does not detonate.

---

I forsee that the solution to a first shell interfering with a second is some delay.  Hit the same spot of armor some
time after it has been hit but the first shell.  This may be a few seconds later.  Or a few days later would work equally well.  I suspect that for as long as people have been launching assaults on armored targets they have hoped for a second hit on armor weakened by some prior first hit.  It is a good strategy and one you can use for your fiction!

Comment: I observe that hitting a tank a meter apart is going to be less effective compared to hitting it closer together. ERA works by disrupting the flow of a HEAT round or by breaking the rod of an AP round so it spreads its energy differently (rods are designed to break now). 2 HEAT or AP shots tailgating would see virtually no shrapnel or explosive force heading their way. The problem with most of your information is that its true for single rounds one at a time. But information about repeat rounds is often absent, and information about simultaneous hits even more so. Thats why I ask the question.

Comment: @Demigan - "simulataneous hits".  How do 2 shells hit that same place at the same time?  How can two things _be_ in the same place at the same time?

Comment: as mentioned there are two options. One is (near) simultaneous hits on the target, with the closest they can hit to each other being virtually touching range. The other option would be they hit the same spot but one at a time. I thought you even alluded to this when you mentioned shots tailgating each other.

Comment: Right; tailgating.  Some of your comments made me think you had something else in mind but those 2 options are the 2 I can think of.

Comment: Something to keep in mind here--you are talking about explosive shells.  HEAT rounds are meant to spall fragments off the inside of the armor, not punch a hole through it.  Hitting the same spot again isn't going to do much.

Comment: @LorenPechtel HEAT rounds do punch a hole through, by using carefully shaped explosives to melt a thin copper sheet into a bolt and project it into the armor at hypersonic speeds.  Look up some modern HEAT combat damage, you'll see some scorching around a pencil-sized hole.  You don't want to be inside a tank that's getting penned by HEAT rounds; getting sprayed with molten copper going 20km/s doesn't sound fun.

Comment: @LorenPechtel you are thinking of a HESH round not a HEAT. HESH is spall, HEAT is plasma lance.

Comment: @Demigan Heat shells are still going to interfere with each other, there is still a spherical explosion from a heat shell, A lot of force is projected forward but an equal amount is projected outward, it is just distributed over a larger area. two side by side hits for pure kinetic impactors should have no additional effect, it is basically the same effect as buckshot.

Comment: @John HEAT shells are interfered with when either the cutting beam is disrupted or the carefully placed explosives inside explode unevenly or are misaligned before detonation. In a pure simultaneous hit the explosions cant misalign the explosives and they cant catch up to the beam to disrupt it. Only if one explodes a bit later than the other could one be disrupted.

Answer (score 2):

> ...isn’t able to damage the armor it’s firing at in single shots.

There’s a very easy solution to this that does not involve complicated fire-control disciplines:

### Don’t aim for the armor.

Tanks in general, not just modern MBTs, have a *lot* of weak points that if hit will put them at least temporarily out of commission. In the rare cases of modern tank-versus-tank combat (which, in reality, hasn’t really been much of a thing since the end of WWII, tanks are usually fighting infantry, troop carriers, or emplacements, not other tanks or tank equivalents), they just aim for destruction of the vehicle as a whole because it’s both possible and more efficient, but there’s no rule that says you have to do that.

The tracks and suspension are the most obvious example such a weak point, and even just a well placed shot with a 30mm machine gun is enough to stop a tank if you aim for the tracks and suspension.

Other favorite targets include the gun sights, the turret ring, the mounting of the gun mantlet, any external fuel tanks (these are a thing even in some ‘modern’ designs, and tend to be less well armored than the rest of the vehicle), and of course the commander if he’s stupid enough to stick his head out. The goal here isn’t to destroy the enemy tank, it’s to make it impossible for it to fight effectively so you can either flank it and shoot weaker armored areas, or just swarm it with infantry (both, if pulled off correctly, will ruin the unlucky tank crew’s day).

To put this differently, I encourage you to find and talk to people who play games like World of Tanks or War Thunder. Neither game is super realistic, but both get a handful of things right, and one of those is that if you’re a light vehicle fighting something you can’t punch through the armor of, the most effective option is to incapacitate it to give your friendly artillery (or bombers, or heavy infantry, or Panzerkampfswagen VIII Maus) an easy target.

Overall, this approach means that your materiel doctrine needs to favor accuracy over stopping power, which is actually a legitimate reason to some extent to want smaller caliber weapons *if* you do not have access to things like modern [APFSDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armour-piercing_fin-stabilized_discarding_sabot) rounds. Depending on your exact choice of munitions, you may not even want smoothbore guns like most MBTs use.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the implications of the accuracy arent part of the question. I want to know what effects simultaneous hits have on the armor, not what aiming for other places on the tank can achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Simultaneous hits on an armored vehicle will produce different result based on the technologies involved, and your fictitious generals will need to understand this and change attack doctrine appropriately.

Against homogeneous (such as cold-rolled steel) armor that is relatively flat (not sloped) compared to your firing angle, simultaneous hits will not make a noticeable difference over a single round hitting. The goal of an AP round is to deform the armor material to breach it. Any round that individually cannot deform the armor material will likely need closer to an order of magnitude increase in stopping power to be able to penetrate said armor.

Using HE rounds (or rounds such as squash-head rounds) come to the same conclusion with a caveat. If a round would cause spalling (internal fragmentation of the armor due to external impact), multiple simultaneous hits would cause proportionately more damage. This can mean the difference between occasionally disabling enemy armor, and reliably doing so. Again though, if 1 round is ineffective, piling more on is not a feasible solution because of how armor works.

Things change if ERA (explosive-reactive Armor) is present, or similar technologies. In the case of ERA, tandem charges can be (most likely poorly) simulated, allowing for the first round to be sacrificed to trigger the armor, which weakens it for the second round to penetrate.

Now that the question is answered as asked, I would point out that your simultaneous hit strategy would be much more effective if your generals started by de-tracking or otherwise immobilizing the enemy armor before planning the firing solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use 90mm shells instead of 120mm ones, then here are some options.

Don't rely on kinetic energy to do the damage.

1. Instead fill the shells with an acid that is incredibly corrosive to steel.  As you hit the tank over and over, you will eventually melt through the armor.
2. Make a "sticky" round filled with thermite.  It hits the tank, sticks to the armour, and then releases so much heat the armor melts.

Comment: Although interesting, I don't think modern shells hold enough thermite. I saw on Mythbusters an entire bucket (much larger than the volume of 130mm) which burned through the bucket and "just" 3 or 4 thin steel plates. They loaded up entire bags across a simple car to burn it in half and barely succeeded. You would need to use some sort of HESH round filled with thermite, and make it a massive artillery round rather than 90mm. The other problem is that I don't know of any acids that can burn through steel fast enough to be useful on the battlefield, unless you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

### Could work, but needs absurdly high accuracy

Modern tanks (including all versions of the Abrams) use metal/ceramic composite armour, and contrary to what other answers say the ceramic component of this does make it highly susceptible to multiple hits on the same plate due to the ceramic shattering. However, because of this (and other reasons of practicality) plates are made as small as possible ([wikipedia claims around 4"/10 cm diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chobham_armour#Structure)). Reliably being able to make multiple hits within such a small area at tank combat ranges of 1km+ is implausible without some kind of magic active guidance for the shells, in reality even the most modern tanks don't do more than aim for centre mass. Tanks firing at tanks also now primarily use APFSDS kinetic energy penetrators, which do not carry explosives to the target (with the almost-exception of depleted uranium being pyrophoric in powder form).

To address your points:

- The grouping of the shot. If they hit a meter away from each other
  they'll do less damage then if the shells are practically touching
  each other when they hit the armor.

As stated, they need to hit the same plate, that's the only real criterion

- The timing of the shot. If they
  hit simultaneously they'll likely do more damage than if they hit
  with 0.1 second between hits.

I'm not sure that two shots could practically hit "simultaneously" enough for it to matter. It would have to be on the same plate faster than the speed of sound in the armour carries the ceramic shattering, which is going to be much faster than a millisecond. Either way, you want the ceramic to shatter before the next shot hits so if anything this would be detrimental.

- The scalability of shots hitting
  simultaneously around a spot. 2 shots will deal less damage then 3
  etc.

After the armour is degraded your shots should penetrate into the crew compartment. Most likely one penetrating shot will do the job.

- Hitting in tandem instead. Hitting the exact same spot, meaning
  that as one shell explodes the next one is almost hitting it as well.

I don't see any advantage here either, other than maybe being more likely to hit the same plate on a moving target.